# Visual Studio .NET References with yellow triangle

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, .net-4.8

I work on a project with one more developer and we share our code via Git, when I clone project, all my references get a yellow triangle with the following warning:

[image: As you can see it in this screenshot]

I want to fix it, I didn't find solutions for this problem. I'll be happy to get your help! Thanks.

Comment: What is the .NET Framework version of your current project? Do you have a higher version of the .NET Framework (such as .NET Framework 4.8) installed on your computer? Typically, we need to ensure that the .NET Framework version of the added references matches the .NET Framework version currently installed on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run NuGet Restore, or run a full build (which calls NuGet restore first)

[image]

In this specific case, the issue is most likely to be that the packages have not yet been loaded.

> In other scenarios it indicates that these references are not binary compatible with the framework version you are compiling. This can happen if you retarget the version of .Net or if you have switched the compilation mode.

If a restore doesn't work, then the following standard advice applies:

If you have upgraded, then you can force the NuGet packages to be re-installed with the same versions this the `Update-Package` command with the `-reinstall` option:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

You could also uninstall the packages and reinstall manually.

If however you have changed the platform target say from `Any CPU` to `ARM32` then the same advice might apply as long as the packages you have selected support the required platform. Otherwise you will need to install other packages that do support that platform.

- If you have changed the target platform accidentally, try changing back to `Any CPU` or `x86`/`x64`

Answer (score 0):

Several reasons can cause for this,

**Check Target Framework** - Make sure your project & referenced assembly target compatible versions of the .NET Framework

**Rebuild Solution** - Sometimes this can resolve references related issues.

**Restore NuGet Packages** - Right click on your project > Restore NuGet Packages

**Version Mismatch** - Differing .NET Framework versions between the projects can cause this, Check your new project's properties to ensure that a different default version isn't being used.

**Reinstall all packages** In all projects of the current solution:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

**Worst-case**,

Remove `< Target >` Maybe with multiple lines `< /Target >` usually found at the bottom of .csproj. Save, load, and re-build the solution.